# Autofac Builder with Two Different Connection

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

I have a ServiceModule class which extends Module:

```
public class ServiceModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        base.Load(builder);
        var ConnA = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnA"].ConnectionString;
        var ConnB = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnB"].ConnectionString;
        builder.Register(c => new SqlConnection(ConnA)).As<IDbConnection>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.RegisterType<ServiceA>().As<IServiceA>();
        builder.RegisterType<ServiceB>().As<IServiceB>();
    }
}
```

My ServiceA:

```
public class ServiceA: GenericRepo<Model>, IServiceA
{
    public ServiceA(IDbConnection conn) : base(conn) { this.conn = conn; }
    public async Task<RModel<Model>> Method(Model model)
    {
        return await ResultGet("ProcedureName", new
        {
            parameters...
        }, parameters...);
    }
}
```

Connection is passed to GenericRepo which has the ResultGet method. This method connects to database via connection and get data.

My GenericRepo:

```
public class GenericRepo<T> : IGenericRepo<T> where T : BaseModel
{
    protected IDbConnection conn;

    public GenericRepo(IDbConnection conn)
    {
        this.conn = conn;
    }
    public async Task<Model<T>> ResultGet(parameters)
    {
        var result = await conn.QueryAsync<T>(parameters);
    }
}
```

So, my question is; how can I register ServiceA with ConnA and ServiceB with ConnB?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: [This heavily overlaps with an Autofac FAQ.](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html)

Comment: Thanks, I already checked that documentation but could not find any useful info. I am not the creator of this structure so I do not have enough knowladge to make very specific changes. Can you please be more specific on the documentation? I do not know which part should I really focus on.

Comment: In the example docs they talk about "this component needs this ISender, the other component needs a different ISender, but they're both the same interface." You're saying the same thing here. Service A needs Conn A, Service B needs Conn B, but both only take IDbConnection. Your IDbConnection is the ISender. You want two different components to get two different things. The whole FAQ is about exactly that - and why it's a bad service design, how to fix it, and what to do if you can't fix it.